# Brain teaser: 2 men can catch 2 fish in 2 minutes, at this rate, how many men can catch 500 fish in 500 minutes?

Tags: arithmetic

I found this interview question off of Quora. I'm unfamiliar with rate-related questions when there are 3 dimensions (men, fish, time).

My intuition is:

- 2 men can catch 2 fish in 2 minutes
- then if you multiply the time unit by 250, these 2 men can duplicate this behavior 250 times, which means they can catch 500 fish

So is the answer 2 men can catch 500 fish in 500 minutes?

In general, how do does one solve these rate questions when there are 3 dimensions? I know when there are two dimensions (for example, if catching 2 fishing takes 2 minutes, then how long does it take to catch 500 fish) you basically do cross-multiply as we learned in high school. An explanation of how to solve this type of problems (preferably with examples) would be much appreciated

Comment: Just arithmetic, not even probability, so off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, you can reduce dimension of the problem.

Here, introduce an unit of man-minute. '2 men can catch 2 fish in 2 minutes' means, that to catch 2 fishes, you have to allocate 4 man-minutes. So rate is 0,5 fish per man-minute.

To catch 500 fishes you have to allocate 1000 man-minutes. That is 2 men fishing for 500 minutes (or eg. 100 men fishing for 10 minutes).